# Another storyboard for password uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode, authentication, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

Is it correct to add new storyboard for "login" and "forget password" view controllers and load it from app delegate?

Comment: Define 'correct'. You can define a view controller, give it an ID, instantiate it and present it all from your existing storyboard.

Comment: yes, but problem that i need vc for "Forget Password" with back button to VC with Login Form...

Comment: Ok, so you add a navigation controller with the login view as the root and a segue to the forgot view. Same logic applies.

Comment: Hm... in this way may be is better to make second storyboard?.. How do you think?

Comment: That's personal preference. A second storyboard will make it easier to manage maybe. Will take a fraction longer at runtime.

Comment: Wain, thanks a lot, if you want, make an answer, i'll accept it=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a personal preference thing. The navigation controller, login view and forgot view (together with the segue) could be created in a new storyboard or your main storyboard. How they are used would be basically the same.

Creating a new storyboard means loading that storyboard at runtime. If the user will usually be logged in automatically (using a saved token or something) then you may get a small benefit from not having these views in the main storyboard. You will get a small cost when loading the storyboard at runtime. Either way, the effect should be negligible.

So, it's really a question of how you want to manage your project. If having the views in a separate storyboard makes it easier for you to manage then go right ahead :-)